# Why I'm getting a Java classpath not found Error in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, classpath

I don't know why I'm getting a classpath not found error in VS Code when I open more than one java program in the same workspace. Also sometimes this error shows up even when I open a single project and run the program. Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it can be fixed by right clicking the project and choosing **Add Folder to Java Source Path**, after that, it may throw another error:

[image]

Click Quick Fix and add package declaration, you can run .java file successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution but Now I'm getting this error - "Error: Could not find or load main class App    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App" .Also the option to quick fix isn't being shown. What can I do next?

Comment: Can you share your current workspace projects in [github](https://github.com/) for me to reproduce your question?

Comment: No need for that as this error is getting shown even for a simple hello world program.

Comment: Will this happen if you just open one program?

Comment: @SunnyRaj. Will this happen if you just open one program?

Comment: I get this error after that : Unsupported operation. Please use pom.xml file to manage the source directories of maven project.